# Calculating ROC AUC for a fair coin by definition. Where's the mistake?

Tags: probability, roc, auc

Here's the formula for a continuous case (taken from [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/367558)):

\begin{align}
\text{AUC} 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \big( 1-F_1(\tau) \big) f_0(\tau) d\tau 
\end{align}

Since a coin assigns scores from $\{0,1\}$ to each instance of positive and negative class with probability 0.5 we have (adopting formula above to the discrete case):

$p_0(1)p_1(score>1) + p_0(0)p_1(score>0) = 0.25$

where $p_0$ and $p_1$ are probability mass functions of scores for negative and positive classes. What's wrong with this reasoning?

I arrive at the same conclusion when considering a finite set of 50 positive and 50 negative instances. A coin would assign around 25 positive scores to instances of each class. There are 50x50 possible ways to choose a pair (one negative and one positive instance) and 25x25 ways to choose a pair such that positive instance is scored 1 while negative is scored 0. Which gives $p=0.25$.