# How to interpret the AUROC curve for mortgage denial/approval?

Tags: classification, auc

My binary variable is whether a mortgage application is denied(1) or approved (0). Let's say I have two classifiers. One with AUROC = 0.75 and the other with AUROC = 0.85. Is it correct to state for example for the second classifier the following? The AUROC value of 0.85 implies that there is an 85% probability that a randomly selected denied observation is ranked higher than a randomly selected approved observation? How is ranked exactly to understand? Does it simply represent the probability that I will classify it as such (here 1)?

Comment: Should be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it/

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  The concordance probability ($c$-index; AUROC) is the probability that a randomly selected subject who had an event has a higher predicted probability than a randomly selected subject who did not have the event.

But note that you are **not** using a *classifier* if you are dealing with risk estimation.

The $c$-index is not a great measure for comparing two predictive models because it is not sensitive enough for that purpose.  One model might have $c=0.84$ and the other $c=0.845$ yet the second be meaningfully better than the first.

Answer (score -1):

The AUROC value of 0.85 implies that a randomly selected denied observation has a precision of 0.85.