# Why is ROC AUC equivalent to the probability that two randomly-selected samples are correctly ranked?

Tags: roc, auc

I found there are two ways to understand what AUC stands for but I couldn't get why these two interpretations are equivalent mathematically.

In the first interpretation, AUC is the area under the ROC curve. Picking points from 0 to 1 as threshold and calculate sensitivity and specificity accordingly. When we plot them against each other, we get ROC curve.

The second one is that the AUC of a classifier is equal to the probability that the classifier will rank a randomly chosen positive example higher than a randomly chosen negative example, i.e. P(score(x+)>score(x−)). 
(from [What does AUC stand for and what is it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it/133435#133435))

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's easy to see once you obtained a closed-form formula for AUC.

Since we have finite number of samples $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$, we'll have finite number of points on the ROC curve. We do linear interpolation in between.

First, some definitions. Suppose we'd like to evaluate an algorithm $A(x)$ that outputs a probability of $x$ lying in the positive class $+1$. Let's define $N_+$ as the number of samples in the positive class $+1$ and $N_-$ as the number of samples in the negative class $-1$. Now, for a threshold $\tau$ let's define False-Positive-Rate (FPR, aka 1-specificity) and True-Positive-Rate (TPR, aka sensitivity):

$$
\text{TPR}(\tau) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N [y_i = +1] [A(x_i) \ge \tau]}{N_+}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\text{FPR}(\tau) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N [y_i = -1] [A(x_i) \ge \tau]}{N_-}
$$

(where $[\text{boolean expression}]$ is 1 if expression is true, and 0 otherwise). Then, ROC curve is built from points of the form $(\text{FPR}(\tau), \text{TPR}(\tau))$ for different values of $\tau$. Moreover, it's easy to see that if we order our samples $x_{(i)}$ (note the parentheses) according to the algorithm's output $A(x_i)$, then neither $\text{TPR}$ nor $\text{FPR}$ changes for $\tau$ between consecutive samples  $A(x_{(i)}) < \tau < A(x_{(i+1)})$. So it's enough to evaluate FPR and TPR only for $\tau \in \{A(x_{(1)}), \dots, A(x_{(N)})\}$. For $k^{\text{th}}$ point we have

$$
\text{TPR}_k = \frac{\sum_{i=k}^N [y_{(i)} = +1]}{N_+}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\text{FPR}_k = \frac{\sum_{i=k}^N [y_{(i)} = -1]}{N_-}
$$

(Note both sequences are non-increasing in $k$). These sequences define `x` and `y` coordinates of points on the ROC curve. Next, we linearly interpolate these points to get the curve itself and calculate area under the curve (Using a formula for area of a trapezoid):

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{AUC} &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{\text{TPR}_{k+1} + \text{TPR}_{k}}{2} (\text{FPR}_{k} - \text{FPR}_{k+1}) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{\sum_{i=k+1}^N [y_{(i)} = +1] + \tfrac{1}{2} [y_{(k)} = +1]}{N_+} \frac{[y_{(k)} = -1]}{N_-} \\
 &= \frac{1}{N_+ N_-} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \sum_{i=k+1}^N [y_{(i)} = +1] [y_{(k)} = -1]
 = \frac{1}{N_+ N_-} \sum_{k < i} [y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}]
\end{align*}
$$

Here I used the fact that $[y = -1] [y = +1] = 0$ for any $y$.

So there you have it: AUC is proportional to the number of correctly ordered pairs, which is proportional to the probability of random pair of samples being ranked according to their labels.

**EDIT (6 years later)**: Since for $a, b \in \{-1, +1\}$ we have $[a < b] = 1$ only when $a = -1$ and $b = +1$, it's easy to see that
$$
\frac{1}{N_+ N_-} \sum_{k < i} [y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}] = \frac{1}{N_+ N_-} \sum_{\substack{k < i \\ y_{(i)} = 1 \\ y_{(k)} = -1}} [y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}]
$$

In essence, we form all possible negative-positive pairs and see what fraction of them is correctly ordered according to our algorithm $A$, that is, $A($positive sample$)\; > A($negative sample$)$.

Comment: Thanks @Barmaley.exe. This is really helpful. Finally connect the dots. A following up question though, is how AUC is equivalent to Mann Whitney U test.

Comment: I don't have an answer to that, but either way it'd not be a good idea to answer another (mostly unrelated) question here. I suggest you create a new thread.

Comment: This is all covered in Hanley and McNeil 1982: https://pubs.rsna.org/doi/10.1148/radiology.143.1.7063747 (Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney equivalence etc.).

Comment: Can you please clarify how did the numerator before the last step is rearranged? where did $1/2[y_(k) =  +1]$ go?

Comment: @christopher, $[y_{(k)} = +1] [y_{(k)} = -1]$ is always 0.

Comment: Hi @ArtemSobolev and thank you for your input. I did not yet carefully think about the derivation but one question though: Is the set $\{A(x_{(1)}), \dots, A(x_{(N)})\}$ enough? I mean when $\tau \in A(x_{(1)})$ everything is classified as positive and when $\tau \in A(x_{(N)})$ only the $(x_{(N)}, y_{(N)})$ sample is classified as positive. Should we still try another threshold like $A(x_{(N)})+c$ where $c$ is e.g. a very small number? Wouldn't this threshold be the case where everything is classified as negative? Wouldn't we now cover all the $(TPR(\tau), FPR(\tau))$ cases?

Comment: To add to the previous, would it be more correct to say instead of: "...it's enough to evaluate FPR and TPR only for $\tau \in \{A(x_{(1)}), \dots, A(x_{(N)})\}$..." that "...it's enough to evaluate FPR and TPR only for $\tau \in \{A(x_{(1)}), \dots, A(x_{(N)})\}$ which cover all the TPR,FPR cases except the one where all points are classified as negative."

Comment: This is a clear answer compared to the answers in the question linked here. But I wonder whether the last part $\sum_{(k < i)} [y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}]$ is really explains what we want here. Since $y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}$ for all $k < i$ based on our ordering. I think some conditioning needs to be there. Specifically $y_{(k)}$ has to be a true negative sample and $y_{(i)}$ has to be a true positive sample.

Comment: @user2939212, I think they are the same thing. Then $y_{(k)}=1$ then $y_{(k)} < y_{(i)}$ is always false, since both $1 < -1$ and $1 < 1$ is false. Same when $y_{(i)} = -1$. Hence the cases when $y_{(i)}$ is not a true positive or $y_{(k)}$ is not a true negative only contribute zeroes to the sum.

Comment: @user2939212, that said, having $N_+ N_-$ as normalizers indeed hints us that we should be enumerating a cartesian product of two sets, one of size $N_+$ and the other of size $N_-$, which is exactly what you're suggesting in the last sentence. I've added a paragraph on that.