# Different visualization of AUC than ROC curve

Tags: data-visualization, roc, auc, model-evaluation

There are multiple interpretations of area under ROC curve. (e.g [What does AUC stand for and what is it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it) ). We also know that AUC is closely related to rank correlation. Are there also different ways how to visualize it?

I am not thinking about the whole curve, but about AUC as a measure. Maybe some scatter plots or histograms that shows the rank correlation, or something related to proportion of pairs of samples with higher predicted probability for positive sample than negative.

Comment: The AUC is a scalar (unitary) value. Anything that represents a single number would do it. Would you be interested in different ways to represent the ROC curve?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand

Answer (score 2):

AUC can be visualized with a scatter plot. Suppose the points in the plot correspond to such pairs of data points in the evaluation set that one of each pair is a negative example `n` and the other one is a positive example `p`. If the x coordinate of a point is the predicted probability of `n` belonging to the positive class and y coordinate is the predicted probability of `p` belonging to the positive class, then the proportion of data points above the diagonal equals AUC.

You can check an example in [this blog post](https://medium.com/balabit-unsupervised/a-new-look-at-an-old-friend-c1936841215f).