# ROC AUC score significance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, auc

I used the `sklearn.metric roc_auc_score`,it gave me a value 0.91.

What is the does this number mean?

I am interested to learn how this is calculated,could someone please direct me to some information on this?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_Operating_Characteristic

Comment: and also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it/132832#132832

Answer (score 1):

I think this is covered in Wikipedia and many other similar posts here. Please look at the comments.

AUC of 0.91 is much better than a random model (AUC=0.5), but it doesn't mean your model is good. You will need to compare your model with a reference model. If your reference model has AUC 0.95, your AUC 0.91 is bad. However, if your reference AUC is 0.70, then your AUC 0.91 is good.

Comment: How would you choose a reference model?

Comment: @NikolasRieble That depends on your problem. Specificity, sensitivity?

Comment: By a reference model do you simply mean another measurement of accuracy/ quality (Specificity, sensitivity)? Or do you mean actually another modell (such as SVM) to compare both performances?