# Why calculating AUC generates 'inf' value

Tags: auc

I use the function `auc` in the `R` package `pROC` to calculate the `auc` value in a simulation study. `test.y` is the observed response, `y_pred_mle` is the predicted response.

```
> test.y
   test.y
1      -1
2      -1
3      -1
4      -1
5      -1
6      -1
7       1
8       1
9       1
10      1
11      1
12      1

> y_pred_mle
        [,1]
76 -166.7094
53 -203.4014
52 -220.0880
51 -189.4703
95 -222.5294
72 -207.0304
24  722.8809
44  727.5353
12  770.5053
42  783.7437
27  733.3144
3   773.2688


> out_auc_mle<- auc( test.y, y_pred_mle  )
> out_auc_mle
[1] Inf
```

I wonder how can this generate `Inf` value? In my understanding on `auc`, the range of `auc` should be `0` to `1`. I am not asking an coding question. I just wonder how the auc value can be `Inf`. Can anybody explain me about is it possible that the `auc` is `Inf`? Then how to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AUC should be 1 for this data because all `1` examples are ranked higher than all `-1` examples. [This is because AUC corresponds exactly to the probability that a randomly-selected positive is ranked more highly than a randomly-selected negative](https://kevincodeidea.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/proof-of-the-auc-is-equivalent-to-probability-of-ranking-positives-over-negatives/). [Matthew Drury has a nice write-up here](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/06/21/auc-proof.html). There must be either an error in usage or a bug, probably the former.

[A useful CV thread on AUC, what it is, and how to interpret it is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer inspires me to solve this problem. But I still wonder about what you said **The AUC should be 1 for this data because all 1 examples are ranked higher than all -1 examples (note the signs)** , why **if all 1 examples are ranked higher than all -1 examples**, we can directly said "AUC" =1? Could you give me some explanation? Many thanks.

Comment: I've added more detail.

Comment: I worte a less technical proof of the AUC equivelence here: http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/06/21/auc-proof.html